# Linux Manjaro XFCE New Install Hangs After Login

Tags: linux, arch-linux, xfce, manjaro

I recently decided to give Manjaro a go and decided to go with the LXCE edition (though I have the same problem with the Gnome edition as well) and so as I usually do install Linux, made a bootable of the iso in DD mode using Rufus and followed the steps of the live installer once I booted it from USB. Nothing unusual happened, took less than 10 minutes. I go to boot it from my new installation and after I hit enter logging in I am left with a splash/desktop background and a mouse that does not move.

Several reboots and reinstalls later and poking about on forums I am still nowhere. The most common advice I've seen is to try and delete some XFCE config files but this appears to be for an older version and I cannot find the files that are referring to. I have also seen a suggestion to try CTRL + Alt + F2 and then CTRL + Alt + F7 to jump between text mode and GUI mode but this only worked for me once and only got me as far as seeing my desktop before it froze again.

I am doing this on an MSI GE73 Raider, any help would be much appreciated!